# gVim escape key does not work on windows 10

Tags: vim, windows-10, vi

I recently started working with a windows machine and installed gVim, but somehow the escape key does not work - rendering gVim practically useless.

Is it possible that my computer sends out an unusual character for the escape key? Is there any way to test this hypothesis?

Or is it a common Windows (10) issue, that escape does not work as on other devices? Did anyone else encounter this strange behaviour?

I tried on linux4windows terminal and there it had the same result yesterday, but now the escape key works fine.

Comment: Have you tried starting gvim from the command line (e.g. gvim -u NONE) and seeing if you can replicate this behavior? Also, could there be a mapping that you are unaware of (e.g. :map would show your mappings)?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but I've been suffering this and finally found some time to dedicate to it.

The answer seems to be (for me at least), that if you hit <kbd>Win</kbd> to open the Start Menu and then type `gvim`, the first option is actually `gVim Easy` *not* `gVim`.

The difference is 'gVim Easy' starts with the `-y` switch:

```
-y   Easy mode (like "evim", modeless)
```

If you launch `gVim` (as opposed to `gVim Easy`) then <kbd>ESC</kbd> works as expected.

I guess the "modeless" in 'Easy Mode' means there aren't normal (command) or insert modes, so there's no need to use <kbd>ESC</kbd> to switch between them.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with gVim 8.0. I updated to 8.1 and left all default settings (no remapping etc..). Now the escape key works again.

[image]

Comment: ...and the escape key does still not work for you ? Have you tried to re-install using the default settings ?

Comment: sorry for slow reply; yes, it does not work at all, and no, i have not tried that, because I use vim on the CMD terminal and vi on the WSL ubuntu terminal without these problems.